# How to skip errors until get a fixed number of valid values?

Tags: r, loops

Suppose I have this simple loop:

```
p<-c(0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.1)

x<-NULL

for (i in 1:100){
    x[i]<-rbinom(1,1, sample(p, 1))
}
```

Here you may expect many `NAs` in `x` due to the possibility of `p=1.1`.

What I want is to have 100 valid elements in `x`. if `p` is random too, I would like to know how to skip the errors in the `for` loop until 100 valid values are generated. I guess `while` should be used here but can't figure out the tricks.

Comment: You could just do `x <- rbinom(100, 1, sample(p[p <= 1], 100, replace=TRUE))`.

Comment: There're some risks to do that, although safe here.

Comment: David, can you say more about what the risks are and under what conditions they could cause a problem?

Comment: If the order in p is matter, your x have risk to mismatch with each element of p because of `length(p[p<=1]) <=length(p)`. It's safe here due to `sample()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sticking to your loop structure

```
i<-1
while(i<100){
    tryCatch({
        x[i]<-rbinom(1,1,sample(p,1))
        i<-i+1

    }, error=function(e){},
       warning=function(w){}
    )
}
```

So we simply catch the errors or warnings, do nothing with them, and only iterate i when there is a non-error run